# Change web banner image based upon country of the visitor

Tags: php, html, geolocation, ip-geolocation

I have a small website (using HTML, PHP and MySQL), and would like to display a specific banner image according to the country of the visitor. Each country has a different banner image.

I have searched Google for solutions and found quite some API's (such as [HostIP](http://www.hostip.info/)) that allow to return the country based upon the IP address. That's nice, but I could not find how to implement it for my purpose to make the image switch according to the country...

I have no developer knowledge. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Well we can but we won't. We're here to help not to give away free code. Maybe you should try to hire a developer ?

Comment: _"I have no developer knowledge"_ - then go hire someone.

Comment: You should not make big blocks of words, it puts people off from answering your question. Note that to create a new paragraph, you need to press [Enter] twice. Once will create a new line in the editor, but not on the actual page where everyone will see your post.
StackOverflow is not a free coding service, and with no developer knowledge you are going to get nowhere. This question will probably be flagged and deleted / closed anyway, so go and hire a developer to write the code for you.

Comment: I'm writing my own code. Everyone has the right to learn. Anyone who does not want to answer or to help, just pass on and ignore the question.

Answer (score 0):

to complete the anwer of Avinash, is this the right solution to switch image based upon country?

```
function switchImage($var) {
    switch ($var)
    {
    case "United states":
      $source = '/images/US.png';
      $class = 'myClass';
      $alt = 'myAlt';
      break;
    case "United Kingdom":
      $source = '/images/UK.png';
      $class = 'myClass';
      $alt = 'myAlt';
      break;
    .
    .
    .
    default:
      return "Default"; //default case
    }
}
```